# What is the Regex pattern "words with numbers in them" but not a number itself

Tags: regex, match

How does a regex look like for

Input:
Rood Li-Ion 12 G6

Match:
"Rood" "Li-Ion" "G6"

1.
I tried
\b[\w-]+\b /g

But that matches the "12" also!

2.I tried

/([0-9]+)?[a-zA-Zê]/

But that didn't match G6.

I want all words even if they have a number in them but I dont want only numbers to match. How is this possible. Whitespace also shall not be part of the match.

"Rood Li-Ion 12 G6" shall become 3 strings of "Rood","Li-Ion","G6"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<!\S)(?!\d+(?!\S))\w+(?:-\w+)*(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ITdaVh/1). It matches strings between whitespaces or start/end of string, and only when this non-whitespace chunk is not a digit only chunk.

Also, it won't match a streak of hyphens as your original regex.

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - a left whitespace boundary
- `(?!\d+(?!\S))` - no one or more digits immediately to the right capped with whitespace or end of string is allowed
- `\w+(?:-\w+)*` - one or more word chars followed with zero or more repetitions of `-` and one or more word chars
- `(?!\S)` - a right whitespace boundary

Comment: and now who shall get the checkmark?! Iam to noob to decide that. Both solutions do what I wanted.

Comment: @nogood The two solutions are different in what they match. You can only find out which one gives you best results when you apply the patterns to real data, we have not seen all of it.

Comment: Wait, what's the reason my comment got deleted? Anyway, glad you found a solution @nogood :)

Answer (score 1):

This should suit your needs:

```
\b[\w-]*[a-zA-Z][\w-]*\b
```